# ngBoilerplate+bootstrap -> navbar not showing right

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, boilerplate, ngboilerplate

I have this ngBoilerplate framework, and I'm trying to build an app. I am really just starting out right now, but can't seem to be able to make the navbar have the right size. It's just as if bootstrab js and css aren't loaded or compiled right.

It now looks like one big container, similar to a jumbotron. But if I replace the lines that compile my js-es and less-es with a path to a different bootstrap instance, specifically to its css and js, it works perfectly.

```
<!-- compiled CSS --><% styles.forEach( function ( file ) { %>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= file %>" /><% }); %>

<!-- compiled JavaScript --><% scripts.forEach( function ( file ) { %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= file %>"></script><% }); %>
```

NOT WORKING, but

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path-to-bootstrap-css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-bootstrap-js"
```

This one shows just fine.
Now I'm not really sure if or where should I tell grunt which files are important to me ... I tried in the build.config.js file, but it doesn't work.

In src/less/main.less I have an "@include path-to-bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less", and in bootstrap.less everything is loaded.

So, as a conclusion, my question is what and where should I put, to make the navbar work ?

To reproduce my bug/misunderstanding, one might download (git clone https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp, update bootstrap to 3.0.3, angular-bootstrap to 0.7.0) and compile the project. Also, add a navbar as in the bootstrap example (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) to index.html.

If it looks nice, as it should, it works. If not, and it looks all bloated and huge, then you're in my spot.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I was seeing an un-styled page with this showing on the top:

```
<% styles.forEach( function ( file ) { %> <% }); %> <% scripts.forEach( function ( file ) { %> <% }); %>
```

Turned out that I was looking into 
..path/ng-boilerplate/**src**/index.html 
instead of 
..path/ng-boilerplate/**build**/index.html 
as the README file instructed.